# easy curve modeling package for transits that fits the data not just the parameters?

Tags: exoplanet, python, planetary-transits, astropy, light-curve

Does anyone have any recommendations for easy-to-use exoplanet transit light curve model fitting packages like batman, but that fits the data, not just the model parameters?

Thank you so much. I need really easy. I'm really bad at coding and need to learn easy things first with coding then I can build. Thank you in advance so much!  I hope I asked that coherently!

Comment: What do you mean by "fits the data and not just the model parameters"?

Comment: What do you mean by "like batman"?

Comment: Most likely this [batman](https://github.com/lkreidberg/batman) - no cape needed...

Comment: ok, so batman does it  Thank you so much! It just seemed too easy. Too good to be a true type of thing. I'm inputting my mid-transit BJD_TDB guesses by eyeballing my lightcurve and entering it by hand, hand, and once I get a good fit that's my time. mid-transit BJD_TDB.  Is that basically it?  Or Is there a way to automate it? I would still tweak by hand right? Its only a few nights a month. Maybe seven. So I have about 25 curves to fit.

Comment: Are there any Batman users out there? I like it. I was wondering is it popular among astronomers? Is it well-liked? What are most people using? I'm doing the photometry with AstroimageJ and then plotting in python, Astropy, and then using the Batman transit light curve fitting package.  I am an Astro undergrad at a major research university.  I'll be a senior in the Fall. This is my summer research, This and a whole different project involving silicon 2 lines in type-1a Sn's.  Therefore my questions will be wildly disparate! And I really appreciate the help!